# Is it possible to run Drush commands during the build stage of a deployment pipeline?

Tags: deployment

Apologies in advance for the long questions.

**Background:**

We are building a 4-step AWS pipeline to deploy our site to an ECS container.

The stages are as follows:

- Source
- Build
- Deploy
- Post-deploy

At the moment we have ECS commands running on Deploy stage to execute the Drush commands(`drush cim -y`/`drush updb -y`/ `drush cr`)

Due to some reason the ECS commands execution is not consistent and we need to run the pipeline twice in order to apply the configuration changes to Drupal. This is not ideal, so, we came up with the idea of adding the Drush commands during the Build stage inside our docker file.

```
FROM amd64/drupal:8-apache

ARG DRUPAL_ENV

ENV DRUPAL_ENV=$DRUPAL_ENV

ARG DB_HOST

ENV DB_HOST=$DB_HOST

ARG DB_PASSWORD

ENV DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install git -y

RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/*

COPY drupal.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

COPY memcache_client/amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902

RUN touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memory_limit.ini

RUN echo "memory_limit = 512M" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memory_limit.ini

RUN touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memcache.ini

RUN echo "extension=amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memcache.ini

RUN touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/file_upload_limit.ini

RUN echo "upload_max_filesize = 256M" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/file_upload_limit.ini

RUN touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/post_size_limit.ini

RUN echo "post_max_size = 256M" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/post_size_limit.ini

WORKDIR /opt/drupal
COPY . /opt/drupal/

RUN /bin/sh -c set -eux;
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data docroot
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data docroot/sites docroot/modules docroot/themes;

RUN ln -sf /opt/drupal/docroot /var/www/html;
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/docroot
RUN chown -R 750 /var/www/html/docroot

RUN alias drush="./vendor/bin/drush"
RUN drush updb -y
RUN drush cim -y
RUN drush cr
```

The above Dockerfile doesn't give us any errors but completes the pipeline. We initially had a problem that the Drush at this stage cannot find the database. After some digging, we realised that during the build stage, it's looking for the DB credentials defined in the `settings.local.php`. Whereas it is meant to be checking the credentials from `settings.stg.php` or `settings.uat.php`. So just to fix this issue we introduced a `.env` file so that we can pass the DB credentials for the particular environment. We also updated our `settings.local.php` to be like this, so that it can read values from the `.env`

```
$databases['default']['default'] = [
  'database' => 'drupal',
  'username' => 'admin',
  'password' => $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'],
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => $_ENV['DB_HOST'],
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
];
```

I know this doesn't sound right at all, but, we just wanted to see what's happening.

After the pipeline is executed, login into Drupal and we can see the config changes for Local applied to Staging/UAT, which is incorrect. We assume this is because we run the Drush commands during the build stage and it can only access configs for local only at this stage.

We have the following logic in our `settings.php` to fetch the settings file per environment.

```
// Set environment to local dev by default.
$env = 'local';

$is_aws_env = isset($_ENV['DRUPAL_ENVIRONMENT']);

// Override AWS environment if available.
if ($is_aws_env) {
  $env = $_ENV['DRUPAL_ENVIRONMENT'];
}

// Set site and environment specific settings.
$settings_file = DRUPAL_ROOT . "/sites/default/settings/settings.{$env}.php";
if (file_exists($settings_file)) {
  require $settings_file;
}
```

**Questions:**

Why exactly the Dockerfile or the Pipeline is looking for `settings.local.php` when it should be looking for the settings file for the current environment?

If we are to run the Drush commands inside a Dockerfile, what's the best stage or way to do that without hacking the `settings.local.php` like how we are doing now?

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Regarding the first question, Drupal is always going to fall back to `settings.php` and `settings.local.php` unless you add some additional logic for it to use a different settings file.  Why do you think it should be looking for another settings file?

Comment: You always run `drush updb` before `drush cim`. Or simply run `drush deploy` which will execute `updb` and `cim` in the right order.

Comment: Thanks @leymannx, I just learned this today that we should always run `drush updb` first. I have changed it in my code, but, that wasn't the fix unfortunately.

Comment: @PatrickKenny I think it should pickup the settings file belongs to the correct environment because we have this in the settings.php

`
// Set environment to local dev by default.
$env = 'local';

$is_aws_env = isset($_ENV['DRUPAL_ENVIRONMENT']);

// Override AWS environment if available.
if ($is_aws_env) {
  $env = $_ENV['DRUPAL_ENVIRONMENT'];
}
$settings_file = DRUPAL_ROOT . "/sites/default/settings/settings.{$env}.php";
if (file_exists($settings_file)) {
  require $settings_file;
}
`

Comment: @Dynamdilshan Please edit the question to include this code.  If you have custom code that is supposed to select the correct settings.php file and the wrong file is being selected, then the problem is with that code.

Comment: Sorry @PatrickKenny, I've updated the question now. I have a feeling because we run the Drush commands during the build stage of the pipeline we don't have the access to the correct ENV variable yet. Just an assumption. Because this code is working for us on our Acquia site, it's just we get this problem with our new stack on AWS.